# Do timeout messages have to be in sagas?

Tags: nservicebus

Some examples of useful timeout features are session expiration notifications, email schedules (for reminders), scheduled calculations, etc...

From what I can see, we have to start a saga for every timeout we want to run. Is there a way to have nservicebus send a message to a handler without having to use a saga?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Timeouts are for sagas only but NServiceBus also have support for scheduling:

http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/scheduling-with-nservicebus

and to defer the sending of a message:

[Deffering messages with nservicebus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19959138/deffering-messages-with-nservicebus)

Comment: I saw the defer sample. Is there any official documentation for this? A google of nservicebus bus.defer gets me stackoverflow questions, which while interesting, is a roundabout way of learning an api.

Comment: also, are there any samples for using the schedular?